# Synchronous run of `preview-document'

Tags: auctex, preview-latex

For replacing `org-html-format-latex` with auctex preview (or more correctly `texfrag`) it would be nice to run auctex preview synchronously.

The code of auctex preview contains several alternatives where `TeX-process-asynchronous` is taken care of.
Nevertheless, if one sets `TeX-process-asynchronous` to nil `TeX-inline-preview-internal` fails.
The most obvious reason is that `TeX-run-command` returns the process status instead of a process id and auctex tries to set the coding system for that "process".
If one skips the coding system issues by adding a check for `TeX-process-asynchronous` one gets the next error in `preview-TeX-inline-sentinel` and that goes on and on.

Is this a bug of auctex preview or has the support of synchronous auctex preview been dropped or even never fully been implemented?

Version info:

- emacs: 25.3.1
- auctex: 11.92.0

Comment: (defcustom TeX-process-asynchronous (not (eq system-type 'ms-dos)) - hmm, could you give some description of your workflow?

Comment: @AndreasRöhler I exploit a slightly modified bounding box calculation from auctex preview via texfrag for org-mode html export. In that way the inline formulas are placed perfectly in the exported html. (Note, that I got something like synchronous auctex preview working with polling and by checking whether the formulas in the LaTeX buffer are finished (either with a preview or a failure).

Comment: Sounds good already. Beside: don't understand what "synchronous" should mean in the context. In other cases saw a queued, delayed execution - which seems not at stake. Rather an automated trigger of the preview - right?

Comment: The meaning of "synchronous" in my context: Embedding the preview code for org html export requires synchronous execution, i.e., the preview images must be ready when my function `texfrag-region-synchronous` returns. I cannot work with sentinels there since I am replacing stuff in the middle of `org-html-format-latex` via an `:override` advice. (It is actually an `:around` but effectively an `:override`, but that are technical details...).

Comment: May you provide resp. point me to some example code?

Comment: @AndreasRöhler The `texfrag` stuff is quite okay. `texfrag-region-synchronous` will be a legitim member of that library. I will release it together with some bugfixes at https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag in near future. The html exporter stuff `orgTZA-html` is written for my own purpose only. I do quite evil stuff therein to get what I need without respect for any coding rules. Don't know yet whether I will really make it public.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler The new version of `texfrag` is commited.